# jQuery Datepicker width too narrow when displaying multiple months

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I'm displaying multiple months on my jQuery datepicker, but I recently increased the font sizes (and padding) to make the calendar a little easier to read.  The problem now is that the overall width of the three calendars is not big enough and the calendars are overlapping.

[image]

(Note: when displaying a single calendar it still works just fine)

Prior to increasing the font sizes the calendars lined up perfectly, but now I can't figure out what class I need to change to make this work.

I don't see any fixed width values in any of these styles, only percentages. I thought maybe changing the width in .ui-datepicker would do the trick but that makes no difference whatsoever.

```
/* with multiple calendars */
.ui-datepicker.ui-datepicker-multi { width:auto; }
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group { float:left; }
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group table { width:95%; margin:0 auto .4em; }
.ui-datepicker-multi-2 .ui-datepicker-group { width:50%; }
.ui-datepicker-multi-3 .ui-datepicker-group { width:33.3%; }
.ui-datepicker-multi-4 .ui-datepicker-group { width:25%; }
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group-last .ui-datepicker-header { border-left-width:0; }
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group-middle .ui-datepicker-header { border-left-width:0; }
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-buttonpane { clear:left; }
.ui-datepicker-row-break { clear:both; width:100%; font-size:0em; }
```

Looking through the Chrome developer tools style inspector I can see that the width for "element style" is set to 51 em, but I can't change it because I guess it's calculated, but based on what?  How is the overall width on multi calendars determined?

EDIT:  Here is where I'm overriding some of the default jQuery UI CSS and where I accomplished the resizing of the calendar.

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger{position:relative;top:0px;float:left}
.ui-datepicker-buttonpane .ui-widget-content{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9)}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title{margin: 0 2.3em; line-height: 2em; text-align: center;}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select{font-size:1.6em; margin:2px 0; background-color:transparent;color:#000000;border-color:transparent}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select .ui-datepicker-month{font-size:1.6em; margin:2px 0; background-color:transparent;color:#404040;border-color:transparent}
.ui-datepicker-header{background-color:white}

div.ui-datepicker-title{background-color:white}
div.ui-datepicker{font-size:10px;background-color:black;opacity:0.75;color:white;border:1px solid transparent;box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #888888}
div.ui-datepicker td{background-color:transparent;color:white;border:1px solid transparent}
div.ui-datepicker td a{background-color:transparent;color:white;border:1px solid transparent}

.ui-dialog{box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
.ui-dialog-content{overflow:visible !important;}
.ui-dialog-titlebar{background-color:".$primarycolour.";color:white;background-image: none;}
.ui-button{border:1px solid ".$primarycolour." !important;background:white !important;background-image:none !important;border-radius:5px}
.ui-button:hover{background:".$primarycolour." !important;color:".$primarytextcolour." !important;}

.ui-widget-content{border:1px solid ".$primarycolour.";background-image:none}
.ui-widget-header{border:1px solid ".$primarycolour.";background-image:none}

.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default{border:1px solid transparent;background-image:none;text-align:center}
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default:hover{border:1px solid ".$quaternarycolour.";background-image:none}
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default{border:1px solid ".$primarycolour." !important;background-image:none}
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default{border-bottom:none !important}
.ui-state-default{border:1px solid ".$primarycolour." ;background-image:none;background-color:".$tertiarycolour."}
.ui-state-active,.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active{border:1px solid ".$quaternarycolour.";background:".$primarycolour." url(images/ui-bg_glass_55_fbcf4b_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;font-weight:normal;color:".$primarytextcolour."}
a.ui-state-default.ui-state-highlight{color:yellow}

.ui-state-active, .ui-state-active .ui-tabs-anchor, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active .ui-state-default {
      background-image: none;
    }

.ui-state-active .ui-tabs-anchor, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active{background-color:white !important;color:black !important;border-color:".$primarycolour." !important}

.ui-datepicker-close{border:1px solid ".$primarycolour."background-color:white}
.ui-datepicker-close:hover{background-color:".$primarycolour.color:".$primarytextcolour."}
.ui-datepicker-current{border:1px solid ".$primarycolour.";background-color:white}
.ui-datepicker-current:hover{background-color:".$primarycolour.";color:".$primarytextcolour."}
```

Comment: Are you using any CSS in addition to what comes with the default jQuery UI package?

Comment: Yes, I have another style sheet where I override some of the default jQuery UI styles.  I've updated my question to show.